Create buffer on stack in x86_64 assembly to print number
when trying to print numbers in assembly instead of number i'm getting O=N84NioR/\_dsPfec IS/pRDNui/0SmL3lSegmentation fault
i'm using Linux with NASM
my code is:
    _printNum:  ;prints number stored in RAX 

        push rax                ;push number onto stack
        mov rcx, 0              ;set counter to 0
        mov rbx, 10             ;set divisor to 10
        _pnl:   ;loop1 - extract digits 

            mov rdx, 0          ;set rdx to 0
            div rbx             ;divide number by 10
            push rdx            ;push remainder
            inc rcx             ;increment counter
            cmp rax, 0          ;repeat until quotient = 0
            jne _pnl
        _pnl2:  ;loop2 - reverse and print

            mov rdi, 1          ;stdout
            mov rdx, 1          ;length of 1 byte
            pop rax             ;pop remainder
            lea rsi, [rax + '0'];convert digit into ASCII character and move it into rsi
            mov rax, 1          ;sys_write
            syscall             ;print digit

            dec rcx             ;decrement counter
            cmp rcx, 0          ;repeat until counter = 0
            jne _pnl2
        pop rax                 ;restore number into rax
        ret

i've tried different register sizes, pointers, pushing counter onto stack but nothing worked
i've tried adding digits to buffer but that resulted in another segfault
    _printNum:  ;prints number stored in RAX 

        push rax                ;push number onto stack
        mov rcx, 0              ;set counter to 0
        mov rbx, 10             ;set divisor to 10
        _pnl:   ;loop1 - extract digits 

            mov rdx, 0          ;set rdx to 0
            div rbx             ;divide number by 10
            push rdx            ;push remainder
            inc rcx             ;increment counter
            cmp rax, 0          ;repeat until quotient = 0
            jne _pnl
        _pnl2:  ;loop2 - reverse and print

            pop rax             ;pop remainder
            add rax, '0'        ;convert digit to ASCII
            mov [rsi + rcx], rax;add digit to buffer
            dec rcx             ;decrement counter
            cmp rcx, 0          ;repeat until counter = 0
            jne _pnl2
        mov rax, 1              ;sys_write
        mov rdx, rcx            ;length of number
        mov rdi, 1              ;stdout
        syscall                 ;print number
        pop rax                 ;restore number into rax
        ret

So I've used debugger and it seems like i need to append the digits to buffer and pass it's adress to rsi, how can i create a buffer on stack?

syscall destroys the contents of rcx. Also write expects a pointer.

How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string) shows working code that uses a buffer on the stack.  It makes one write syscall at the end, and uses 8-bit stores to memory not 64-bit mov [rsi + rcx], rax.

Is this code being called from C, or from another asm routine? It doesn't follow Linux C calling conventions.
